# Assign return value to variable warning

Tags: return-value, concept, method-call

In netbeans I use to call a method that returns a value, but I am directly calling it where I have to pass a parameter to the function i.e. `Function(getValue())` where `getValuue()` returns String. So what I want to know is that what is more efficient way to call this method whether should I assign value to a `string` first and then pass that value to parameter, as netbeans suggests me and shows a warning there, or calling it directly is good? I know code runs fine but keeping in mind the efficiency or rules of coding should I consider this thing or not? Or how badly can it effect if I ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using that value once, then calling it directly where it is used as a parameter is fine.

In Java, this is fine:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myFunction(myClass.getSomeValue());
```

Whereas in the following case:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
MyOtherClass myOtherClass = myClass.someLongComputation();
Int value = myFunction(myOtherClass);
anotherFunction(value, myOtherClass);
```

It may be better to have a local variable so that you avoid calling a long running calculation twice. However, for simple `getValue()`s, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: calling around a couple of times, but keeping in mind about memory and efficiency, how does it effect?